# Prevent certain numbers from printing

Tags: python

Sorry for the bad title. Here is my code:

```
import math
# Finds the square root of a number
def square_root():
    square_root = math.sqrt(int(raw_input('What number do you want the Square Root for')))
    print "The square root of is: %d " % (square_root)
```

Basically, I want to prevent the user from entering a number which doesn't end in 0, 1, 4, 6, 9 or 25 so I can only output perfect squares. I sort of have an idea of what to do but I can't for the life of me recall the terminology to get a decent Google search going so I came here.

I know it will involve some form of `if` and something that looks like this `[1:3]`.

Comment: The code is coming "out weird" because you use tabs not spaces...

Comment: `[1:3]` is a slicing operation, perhaps that'll help your google searches.

Comment: 525 isn't a perfect square... do you keep that? 769? etc, there are infinitely many...

Comment: I'm not sure about your math, are you sure, there is no other way to check the property your looking for besides the ending of the number?

Comment: It's a necessary but not sufficient criteria for being a perfect square. In other words, all perfect squares end in 0, 1, 4, 6, 9, or 5, but not all numbers ending in 0, 1, 4, 6, 9, or 5 are perfect squares. The fact can be used to quickly reject obviously wrong inputs - for example, 17 - but it can't be used to verify that all inputs are correct.

Comment: Yeah I feel suitably embarrassed now. Thanks for all the help though and I'll be sure to format correctly in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure the input is a perfect square, try something like this:

```
def square_root():
    sqrt = int(raw_input("What number do you want the square root for? ")) ** 0.5
    if sqrt == int(sqrt):  # i.e. 'sqrt' is an integer
        print "Result is", int(sqrt)
    else:
        print "That is not a perfect square!"
```

Just checking if the input ends in the numbers you mentioned will not be sufficient (as one of the comments mentioned). Of course, if you still wanted to check that you could just use `str(input).endswith(SOME_VAL)`.

Comment: Why `input()` instead of  `raw_input()`?

Comment: Either could be used here I suppose

Comment: You don't need evaluation of any arbitrary expression here, so `input()` is oversized at best (and a security risk at worst).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read your input to a string. Then, test your string for certain endings with the `s.endswith('test')` method. If successful, convert the input to an integer while expecting a `ValueError` to happen (catch this one with a `try`/`except ValueError:` statement). If everything went well, calculate the square root and print it.

Your test on certain endings does not make sense mathematically. But that is a different topic. Let's use your request as programming exercise :) This code (untested) hopefully does what you want:

```
import sys
import math

tests = ['0', '1', '4', '6', '9', '25']
input = raw_input('What number do you want the square root for? ')
result = (input.endswith(t) for t in tests)
if any(result):
    try:
        print math.sqrt(int(input))
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number."
```

`(input.endswith(t) for t in tests)` is a generator expression. It does not return a list, rather it returns an iterable object, also called iterator. This is what `result` is. The elements in `result` are only computed when requested. `any(result)` goes through this sequence and requests one test result after the other until it finds the first that evaluates to `True`. It then returns `True` itself. If all of the values in the `result` sequence are `False`, also `any()` returns `False`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=map(int,str(123456))

>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> a[-1]
6

>>> a[-1] in [0, 1, 4, 6, 9, 25]
True
```